# python _iter__ does not work with @classmethod

Tags: python

This program is working perfectly

```
 class Iteration:
    def __init__(self,*data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.data):
            raise StopIteration()
        data = self.data[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return data
class Iterable(Iteration):
    lis=[]
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1,3,4,5,3]
    def __iter__(self):
        return Iteration(self.data)

for i in Iterable():
    print(i)
output:
[1, 3, 4, 5, 3]
```

When i trying to run this program is not running

```
class Iterator:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.data):
            raise StopIteration()
        data = self.data[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return data
class Iterable(Iterator):
    lis = []
    @classmethod
    def _range(cls,data):
        if data == -1:
            return cls(sorted(Iterable.lis))
        if data != -1:
            Iterable.lis.append(data)
        data = Iterable._range(data-1)
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        print(self.data)
    def __iter__(self):
        return Iterator(self.data)
i = Iterable._range(10)
output:
None
for i in Iterable.range(10):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
   TypeError
   Traceback (most recent call last)
      <ipython-input-219-982b178ff9a6> in <module>()
      1 i = Iterable._range(10)
      2 print(i)
----> 3 for i in Iterable._range(10):
      4     print(i)

   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I'm trying to replicate the python `range()` function by using `classmethod` decorator and special method dunder(iter) when i try to run `print(self.data)` it displayed output correctly when i try to instance the class and run the `print(i)` it does not working...

Comment: Your first example is NOT, in fact, "working perfectly" - your supposed iteration loop is only executing one time, printing out the entire input list as a single item.  Removing that one asterisk would probably fix it.

Comment: thank you ,but i want second code to be solved,I want to know why second code getting error...

Comment: I just posted an answer but I still don't understand why you want to define a classmethod. The data is supposed to be kept within each instance of your iterator. In a class method you won't get the self to get that instance data. And I see no point in sharing data between the iterator instances at class level...

Answer (score 0):

Of course we have `range` and don't need to do this.

But as you are studying it, why not just do it like this:

```
class Iterator:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.data = list(range(limit)) 
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == len(self.data):
            raise StopIteration()
        data = self.data[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return data

    @property
    def last(self):
        return self.data[-1]

#it = Iterator(10)
#while it:
#    print(next(it))

print(Iterator(3).last)
print()

for value in Iterator(5):
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Iterator:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.data):
            raise StopIteration()
        data = self.data[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return data
class Iterable(Iterator):
    lis = []
    data1 = 0
    @classmethod
    def range3(cls,data):
        while(not Iterable.data1==data+1):
            Iterable.lis.append(Iterable.data1)
            Iterable.data1 = Iterable.data1+1
        return cls(Iterable.lis)
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
    def __iter__(self):
        return Iterator(self.data)
```

output:

```
  test = Iterable.range3(12)
  repr(test)
  <__main__.Iterable object at 0x7f72e050e908>'
  for i in Iterable.range3(12):
    print(i)
 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

finally i figured out due to recursion it is not worked..so i changed to while loop...